# Divisibility, LCM and GCD for fractions (rationals)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

how do i find lcm of two fractions?  For example:

$\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{5}{8}$

Comment: The lcm is not unique since $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.

Comment: Do you mean least common denominator?

Answer (score 9):

A notion of gcd and lcm for rationals arises naturally by extending the divisibility relation from integers to rationals, i.e. for rationals $\rm\:r,s,\:$ we define $\rm\:r\:$ divides $\rm\:s,\:$  if $\rm\ s/r\:$ is an *integer*, $ $ in symbols $\rm\:r\:|\:s\:$ $\!\iff\!$ $\rm\:s/r\in\mathbb Z\: $  [such divisibility relations induced by subrings are discussed further [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242)].

Then, as [proved here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/145167) we have these dual formulas for $\,\rm\color{#c00}{reduced}\,$ fractions $\rm \,a/b,\ c/d$

$$\rm\ gcd\left(\frac{a}b,\frac{c}d\right) = \frac{gcd(a,c)}{lcm(b,d)}\ \ \ if\ \ \ \color{#c00}{\gcd(a,b) = 1 = \gcd(c,d)}$$

$$\rm\ lcm\left(\frac{a}b,\frac{c}d\right) = \frac{lcm(a,c)}{gcd(b,d)}\ \ \ if\ \ \ \color{#c00}{\gcd(a,b) = 1 = \gcd(c,d)}$$

Some of these ideas date to Euclid, who computed the greatest common measure of *line segments*, by anthyphairesis (continually subtract the smaller from the larger), i.e. the subtractive form of the Euclidean algorithm. Euclid's method's become clearer when one learns about *fractional* ideals. The above methods work much more generally since they do not require the existence of a Euclidean (division) algorithm but, rather, only the existence of (certain) gcds.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, it's not quite clear what you're asking for.  I'll suppose that you want the smallest positive rational number $m$ that is an *integer* multiple of both $\frac23$ and $\frac58$. Contrary to the comment above, this *is* well-defined.

To calculate this, we want $m = \frac23a = \frac58 b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, and $m$ is as small as possible.  We can multiply through by 24 to get $16a = 15b$.  The smallest integer $a$ and $b$ satisfying this is clearly $a=15, b=16$, because 16 and 15 are relatively prime.  So the least common multiple $m$ of $\frac23$ and $\frac 58$ is $$\frac23\cdot15 = \frac58\cdot16 = 10.$$

---

In general we can proceed the same way. Say we want the LCM of $\frac ab$ and $\frac{a'}{b'}$. That is, we want to find integers $p$ and $q$ such that $p\frac ab = q\frac{a'}{b'}$.  We can remove the denominators by multiplying both sides by $\def\lcm{\operatorname{lcm}}\lcm(b, b')$, which is equal to $bb'\over \gcd(b, b')$ by a theorem you have probably seen already.  This gives us $$ pab' = qa'b .$$

This is solved by letting $m = \lcm(ab', a'b)$ and then $p=\frac m{ab'}, q=\frac m{a'b}$. The final answer is then $p\frac ab = q\frac{a'}{b'} = {m\over bb'}$.

In your example above we had $m = \lcm(ab', a'b) = \lcm(2\cdot 8, 5\cdot 3) = \lcm(16, 15) = 240$, so the final answer was ${240\over 3\cdot 8} = 10$, and the general solution is $$ \lcm\left(\frac ab, \frac{a'}{b'}\right) = {\lcm(ab', a'b)\over bb'}$$

Answer (score 0):

The lcm of $3$ and $8$ is $2^3*3 = 24$.

(So if you want $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{5}{8}$, you write them as $\frac{16}{24} + \frac{15}{24} = \frac{31}{24}$.

Note that fractions don't have an lcm, their denominators (their bottomy-bits) have an lcm!

Generally, the lowest common multiple is found by splitting the two numbers nto their prime factors, and taking the larger power of each.

Comment: No, there is a standard extension of LCM and GCD to fractions, e.g. see my answer. The idea is ancient - dating back to Euclid.