# How can LCM(1/x, 1/y) be calculated?

Tags: least-common-multiple

How can $\text{lcm}\left(\dfrac{1}{x},\dfrac{1}{y}\right)$ be calculated?
where x and y are integer numbers.
Is it $\left(\text{lcm}(x,y)\right)^2$?
Please provide proof if possible.

Let me explain by example what I am trying to find out:

let's suppose we have two periodic signals. The first signal peaks or triggers 3 times per second. The second signal triggers 7 times per second.
We need to calculate when will the two signals trigger simultaneously in time, with the further restriction that the solution must be an exact (integer) number of seconds.

My intuition says: hey, let's use $\left(\text{lcm}(3,7)\right)^2$ = 441 ...Hey! It seems to work. On the 441th second, both signals do trigger at the same time. This follows from 441 exactly dividing $\dfrac{1}{3}$ and $\dfrac{1}{7}$.
So now I want to know if this is a general solution to the problem and also if 441 is in fact the smallest interval of time where both signals trigger at the same time.

Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @vadim: Given any $R$-module $M$ (such as $\mathbb{Q}$ viewed as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module) it makes sense to talk about the divisibility relation on elements of $M$ defined by $x \mid y$ iff $\exists r \in R : y = rx$.

Comment: Um,  they trigger simultaneous after *1* second.

Comment: The answers everyone gave before your explanation still solve your explanation.  Hurkyl's answer is best and shows the will synch in 3*7/lcm[3,7] = 21/21 = 1 second.

Comment: " the first signals triggers 3 times per second, so, it ticks at 0.3sec, 0.6sec, 0.9sec, 1.2sec, 1.5sec "  Um, that is *not* 3 times a second.  Three times a second is tick on 0.33333333, 0.6666666, and 1.0.  If you *really* do mean it ticks on .3 and .6 etc.  then you want lcm[3/10, 1/7] = 10 seconds.

Comment: thanks @fleablood:
 
Sorry , may be I am very poor at explaining the question. I'll improve on the example... the first signals triggers 3 times per second, so, it ticks at 0.3333sec, 0.6666sec, 0.9999sec, 1.3333sec, 1.6666sec ... I also forgot to explain that I am looking for an answer which is an exact number of seconds, not only simultaneity on time continum. I edited the example to explain better.

Comment: Look.  It ticks at 1 second, right?  Now the other one ticks at 1/7, 2/7.... 6/7, 1.  They *both* tick on 1 second.  That *is* an exact number. not a "time continum".  Why are you insistent that isn't an acceptable answer?  The answer is 1.  441 in *not* the smallest.  *1* is the smallest.

Comment: ok, it was a stupid question. The answer is 1 second. I missed the fact that all my signals were exact divisors of 1 second!

Comment: It was not a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199852/least-common-multiple-of-fractions/199905#199905) regarding the extension of lcm and gcd to rational numbers, we have:

$$\textrm{lcm}\left(\frac1x, \frac1y\right) = \frac{\textrm{lcm}(1,1)}{\textrm{gcd}(x,y)} = \frac{1}{\textrm{gcd}(x,y)}.$$

---

**Edit**: To address your specific example, we have $x=3, y=7$, so
$$\textrm{lcm}\left(\frac13, \frac17\right) = \frac{\textrm{lcm}(1,1)}{\textrm{gcd}(3,7)} = \frac11 = 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

1/x*(x/gcd(x,y)) = 1/gcd(x,y)

1/y*(y/gcd(x, y)) = 1/gcd(x,y) so 1/gcd(x,y) is a multiple.

If n = n'/x = (n'/x')*(1/gcd(x,y)) where x' = x/gcd(x,y) and n = n~/y= (n~/y')*(1/gcd(x,y)) where y' = y/gcd(x,y) is another,  than n is a multiple of 1/gcd(x,y) so 1/gcd(x,y) is the least common multiple.

The LCM(a/b, c/d) = lcm(a,c)/gcd(b,d) = ac/gcd(a,c)gcd(b,d) (similar reason).

=== old incomplete and slightly wrong answer ====

1/x * x = 1.  1/y*y =1.  So 1 is a common multiple.  Is there positive integer smaller than 1?

Comment: Actually my answer is wrong.  I assume lcm by definition was an integer.  It need not be.  so 1/gcd(x,y) is the right answer.

Comment: yeah, I noticed, so I changed the correct answer to Theophile's. I upvoted yours, though, because it solved my particular problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply $\dfrac1{\gcd(x,y)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that

$$ \mathrm{lcm}(ab, ac) = a \mathrm{lcm}(b, c) $$

so we can just multiply through by a common denominator to reduce it to an integer problem:

$$ \mathrm{lcm}(xy \cdot \frac{1}{x}, xy \cdot \frac{1}{y}) = xy \mathrm{lcm}(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{y}) $$

or

$$ \mathrm{lcm}(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{y}) = \frac{\mathrm{lcm}(y, x)}{xy} $$