# Is the divisibility symbol (vertical bar) defined for rational numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

Can I use

$k \in \mathbb{Q}, M_{k} = \{c~|~c \in \mathbb{Q} \land k|c \}$

to mean the set of all multiples of $k$? Or in other words, is the $|$ operator defined for rational numbers?

I was confused as the German version of the wikipedia entry for the vertical bar seems to limit its applicability to integers:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senkrechter_Strich

(for those who can read it)

**Edit:**

I guess I confused $x|y$ to evaluate to true for rational numbers if $\frac{x}{y} \in \mathbb{Z}$. I guess @G Tony Jacobs anticipated my mistake and recommend I use $\{ nk | n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

**Edit:**

In fact, I wanted to use the vertical bar notation as building block to express the following:

$f(x,y) = \text{the smallest number $z$ so that $z = xa, a \in \mathbb{Z} \land z = xb, b \in \mathbb{Z}$}$

Maybe there is an idiomatic mathematical notation for this?

I posted somewhat of a follow-up here: [Does the following hold true and how to learn how to solve this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324451/does-the-following-hold-true-and-how-to-learn-how-to-solve-this)

Comment: I would edit your question to ask if “divisibility” is defined between two rational numbers.

Comment: In the integers, $a \mid b$ means that there exists some integer $k$ such that $b = ka$.  Presumably, the same definition would apply to the rationals, but then $a \mid b$ for *any* rational numbers $a$ and $b$, as we can always find some rational number $k$ such that $b = ka$ (indeed, this number is $\tfrac{b}{a}$).  This doesn't seem like a meaningful definition.

Comment: @XanderHenderson It is a meaningful definition, as it is defined in all algebra books for all integral domains, so even for fields. Of course, it is somehow like the empty set in set theory. But this is important, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I should rephrase:  this doesn't seem like a useful (rather than meaningful) definition in a *field*, such as $\mathbb{Q}$.  Obviously, the definition makes sense, I just don't see the utility of it in this setting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Divisibility, LCM and GCD for fractions (rationals)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199852/divisibility-lcm-and-gcd-for-fractions-rationals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the set of all integer multiples of $k$, you should write $$\{nk:n\in\Bbb{Z}\},$$ or more compactly: $$k\Bbb{Z}.$$

If you want the set of all rational multiples of $k$, that's just $\Bbb{Q}$ again anyway, as long as $k\ne 0$.

---

The divisibility relation can be defined in any commutative ring $R$, by the rule: For $a,b\in R$, we say $a|b$ if there is a $c\in R$ such that $ac=b$.

The rational numbers *do* form a ring, but it is also a field, and we usually don't bother talking about divisibility in a field (although it is well-defined), because every non-zero element divides every element, so there's nothing to talk about. Divisibility in interesting in $\Bbb{Z}$ and other rings that aren't fields, because some integers divide each other, and some do not!

If you're using the symbol to mean "divisibility with an integer quotient".... What you've written isn't a good notation for that, because the symbol is well-defined in any ring. Here, $\Bbb{Q}$ is the only ring mentioned in your OP, so readers would be liable to interpret the symbol as divisibility in $\Bbb{Q}$. If that *is* what you intend, for whatever reason, then it might still be worth specifying, for those unaccustomed to talking about divisibility in fields.

Comment: Only because  some divisibility isn't really something we talk about, it doesn't mean it is not good. For example, in the integers, we don't talk too much about $1\mid b$, but it is not bad. So, divisibility in $\Bbb Q$ is not bad, just not too interesting.

Comment: I don't think anyone's claiming that divisibility in $\Bbb{Q}$ is bad :) I'm saying it's a bad notation if we're trying to use it to mean divisibility by an integer only.

Comment: You wrote:"Divisibility in $\Bbb Q$..., so it's not a good notation". I think, the notation is perfectly correct and good - just not too exciting. The OP asked in his title only, if he can use the symbol for rational numbers. Answer: yes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I wrote that in the context of the paragraph, which made the intent clear to me, but if you want to disagree with how I worded it, that's fine :) Maybe I'll reword it, if I think I can improve it. Thanks again.

Comment: I think your answer is fine. I just disagree that the notations should not be used for fields. It is defined for all integral domains.

Comment: Ok, I haven't claimed that the notation shouldn't be used for fields. I think you're right :)

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify

Comment: or even just $k\mathbb Z$

Comment: I don't know the definitions but it seems to me that $3|\frac{1}{3}$ qualifies. I don't know if $3|\frac{3}{16}$ qualifies. Food for thought.

Comment: @poetasis, if 1/3 is as good as 9, then why isn't 3/16 as good as 24?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs  Sorry, I mean, when When $\frac{1}{3}$ divides $\frac{1}{3}$ you get $1$, an integer. When $3$ divides $\frac{3}{16}$. you get $\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: @poetasis Oh, I see. Then you're saying what I thought OP was saying. When you wrote $3|\frac13$, I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

No, divisibility is not restricted to integers. We can define $a\mid b$ in any integral domain $R$ by the property that there exists an element $c\in R$ such that $b=ac$. This can be translated to principal ideals, i.e., *to contain is to divide*: we have $a\mid b$ if and only if $(a)\supseteq (b)$.
Of course, if $R$ is a field, this is not very useful, as all nonzero elements are units.

Comment: But $\mathbb{Q}$ as an integral domain is really boring as every element is a unit. Hence, $a|b$ is always true for $a\neq 0$.

Comment: @yametekudasai Yes, but this was not the question (see the title). Nevertheless $a\mid b$ is defined and makes sense.

Comment: I think the correct generalization uses that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}$. So $s|r$ happens iff $\frac{r}{s}\in \mathbb{Z}$. This translate to $(s)\supset (r)$ as *fractional ideals* of $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e, here $(s)=s\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Of course you are right with that. The thing is that $\mathbb{Q}$ has much more arithmetic structure than an arbitrary field, so forgetting that extra structure is just too naive. For example $\mathbb{Q}$ is also a UFD, every element has a unique factorization equal to just itself, but that is not interesting at all. Much more interesting is the fact that every element can be written uniquely as $$\pm p_1^{\alpha_1}\dots p_k^{\alpha_k}$$ for some prime numbers $p_i$ and $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{Z}$. This comes from being the fraction field of a *non trivial* UFD.

Comment: Yes, you are also right with that. I think, I focused more (too much) on the title question rather than on arithmetic. And for the title question the answer is (quite trivially) "yes".