# Is the following valid and how to learn how to solve this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Like I stated in the title, I am interested in whether the following always holds true:

$\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}( \forall y\in\mathbb{Q} (x\mathbb{Z} \cap y\mathbb{Z} \neq \emptyset))$

and how to go about solving this question. Note that I am not a mathematician and I am also too old to become one. Still I am eager to learn though.

Comment: $x\mathbb{Z} \cap y \mathbb{Z}$ does not seem to be well-formed. What do $x\mathbb{Z}$ and $y\mathbb{Z}$ mean?

Comment: It probably means $\{xz \mid z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: I used the notation suggested in the accepted answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324380/is-the-divisibility-symbol-vertical-bar-defined-for-rational-numbers

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for any $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $x \mathbb{Z} \ni 0$. Thus, $x \mathbb{Z} \cap y \mathbb{Z} \supset \{0\}$. The answers below give more elements that must be in this intersection.

Comment: I think the OP might have been happier with a proof that $xZ^+ \cap yZ^+ \neq\emptyset$. Your proof works even lightening the restrictions on $x$ and $y$ to $x, y \in \Bbb C$. Of course, then the problem should have said $\Bbb z^+$ rather than $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the statement is valid in ordinary ZF arithmetic.

The proof is sketched as follows:

For arbitrary $x \in \Bbb Q$ there exists $p,q \in \Bbb Z$ such that $x=p/q$.  Similarly, there exists $r,z \in \Bbb Z$ such that $y=r/s$.

Now consider the least common multiple of $q$ and $s$; call that $t$.  Since 
$$xt = \frac{t}{q} p  
$$
and by the definition of least common multiple $\frac{t}q \in \Bbb Z$, we have $xt \in \Bbb Z$.  Similarly, $yt \in \Bbb Z$.

Now consider $xtyt = x (tyt) = (xtt) y$.  Since $ty$ is an integer, so is $tyt$, so $x(tyt) \in x\Bbb Z$. Since $xt$ is an integer, so is $xtt$, so $(xtt)y \in x\Bbb Z$.  Therefore, $xyt^2$ is in both $ x\Bbb Z$ and $y\Bbb Z$ so their intersection is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

let $x = \frac {p}{q}$
let $y = \frac{r}{s}$

$rqx = pr = spy$

$pr \in x\mathbb Z\cap y\mathbb Z$